# Handling a dependent null in linear regression

Tags: regression, missing-data, mnar

I have a linear regression model where I predict a user's completion rate for a specific game. The training data looks like this:

| User Predictor variables | Game Predictor Variables | Completion rate of user i for game j |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user 1 features i.e. age, gender | game 1 features i.e. prize_amount( USD), entry_amount( USD) | value from 0 to 100% |
| user 1 features | game 2 features | value from 0 to 100% |
| user 2 features | game 1 features | value from 0 to 100% |
| user 2 features | game 2 features | value from 0 to 100% |

**Audience:**
Every user in my training data has at least seen the game. Users who just view a game but don't start are given a completion rate of 0.

**Use case:**

1. I take n users and match them to 10 games. So I get 10n rows.
2. Each user gets 10 predicted completion rates. 1 for each game.
3. For each user, the game with the highest predicted completion rate is recommended to them.

**My question is:**

For some games, the **prize_amount** is fixed (i.e. USD100) and the **entry_amount** is fixed (i.e. USD10). And that's fine. My problem is that some other games have a **prize_amount** twice the **entry_amount** that the user decides to pay, this could be as small as USD0.1. In other words, the user decides how much to pay as an **entry_amount**, and will win twice the **entry_amount** as their **prize_amount**. Note that there is a maximum **prize_amount** for these 'double reward' games.
So I don't know what value to put as **prize_amount** and **entry_amount**.

My solution would be to create a new dummy feature call it **reward_type** that takes a 1 for the 'double reward' games and a zero for the 'fixed reward' games. And to put a zero for the **prize_amount** of the 'double reward' games.

for example:

| Age | reward_type | prize_amount | entry_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 23 | 0 | USD1000 | USD10 |
| 23 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 25 | 0 | USD200 | USD100 |

Doesn't this result in a bias for **prize_amount**? i.e. if the double reward games are very popular then the model will favour a **prize_amount** of 0.

Note here the missing values of **prize_amount** and **entry_amount** are entirely dependent on **reward_type**.

I do not know the **entry_amount** at the time of prediction.

This is similar to but not a duplicate of [Handling Null value in Logistic Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228622/handling-null-value-in-logistic-regression).

Comment: A dummy for reward type is a good idea but why would you record zero for the double reward games and not the amount specified by the participant?

Comment: For the 'double reward' games, I do not know the entry_amount at the time of prediction. The user must actually play the game and pay to get that value. For the 'fixed reward' games, the entry and prize are predetermined before the game starts.

Comment: This is *real time* prediction? Regardless, you are making a prediction *only* for the most recent game where the information wrt entry_amount is unknown. There exists a temporal sequence of completed games leading up to the most recent one where that information is available, is it not? Why wouldn't you use that information, assuming it's avaiable?

Comment: Each row of the training data represents a user who has taken part in game j. At the time that they took the game, I have information about their previous games. i.e. win rate, number of games started, etc... and yes I am planning to use them.

Comment: Ok...my preference for structuring this data would *not* be for a single summary row for each user but, rather, a row for each user*game j combination. This structure is much simpler from a data management pov as it amounts to an easily updateable transaction-type database, i.e., with each new game, simply add a row. It's also more informative wrt a participant's behaviors, history and completed (or not) performance across the j games. FWIW.

Comment: You'd also want an interaction term between the dummy and the amount. That would reflect that not all 0s are the same.

Comment: @Mike_Hunter, perhaps I was not clear in my explanation, but this is exactly how my data is structured. But in additon, each user i, game j combination has a history of user i up to that point in time. Will edit question.

Comment: @Björn Will test it out. But I can see all my interaction terms will all be zero, i.e. given table above 1*0, 0*1000, 1*0, 0*200.

Comment: You probably should define the flag the other way around for that purpose.